# Display image from models

Tags: django

I am a beginner in Python and Django. I don't know how to display images from models.

Here's my code:

models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    content = models.TextField(max_length = 5000)
    publication_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photo',verbose_name='My Photo')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
 def index(request):
    songs = models.Blog.objects.all()
    context = Context({
        'songs_list': songs
        })
    return render(request, 'music.html', context)
```

music.html

```
{% if songs_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for songs in songs_list %}

        <li>
            <span style= "color:green">  {{songs.title}}</span>
            <span style= "color:red"> - {{songs.author}}</span>
            <img src="{{ songs.image }}" />      
        </li>

    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No song is made. </p>
{% endif %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'blog.views.index', name='index'),
]
```

When I load page, it doesn't display images, please check out the link to see picture: http://postimg.org/image/i1c8ju9e5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use the [`.url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url) attribute of a `ImageField` to display the image in your template.**

Change `{{songs.image}}` to `{{songs.image.url}}` in your template and it should display the image in your template.

```
{% if songs_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for songs in songs_list %}

        <li>
            <span style= "color:green">  {{songs.title}}</span>
            <span style= "color:red"> - {{songs.author}}</span>
            <img src="{{ songs.image.url }}" />      
        </li>

    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No song is made. </p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: it's still not work. From the terminal:    [15/Sep/2015 18:05:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 921
[15/Sep/2015 18:05:23] "GET /photo/AllByMyself.jpg HTTP/1.1" 500 83073
- Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 43547)
[15/Sep/2015 18:05:23] "GET /photo/HotelCalifornia.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 500 83143
- Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 43548)
[15/Sep/2015 18:05:23] "GET /photo/Hello.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 500 83003
- Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 43550)
[15/Sep/2015 18:05:23] "GET /photo/TakeMeToYourHeart.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 500 83163

Comment: Please check if images are at the correct path and you have configured the settings properly. Also check the value of `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` is defined correctly.